# Typo3 Content Wrapping insted of <div id="c8" class="csc-default"> my own div <div id="c8" class="colContent"> my content 1 </div>

Tags: typo3

From border content area I am adding 3 different content area for display the front end. every time this content will wrap `<div id="c8" class="csc-default"> aaaa </div><div id="c9" class="csc-default"> aaaa </div> <div id="c10" class="csc-default"> aaaa </div>`

Simple I want it warp under something below like `<div id="c8" class="colContent"> my content 1 </div> <div id="c9" class="colContent"> my content 2 </div> <div id="c10" class="colContent"> my content 3 </div>`

or

```
<div id="c8" class="csc-default colContent"> my content 1 </div><div id="c9" class="csc-default colContent"> my content 2 </div><div id="c10" class="csc-default colContent"> my content 3 </div>'
```

How can I wrap content like I want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether thats what you're looking for, but have you tried something like this?

```
# Append another wrap to the content elements
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40 = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40 {
  key.field = colPos

  # If nothing other colPos case is set below
  default = TEXT
  default.value = colDefault
  default.noTrimWrap = | ||

  # 10 is in this case the colPos 10 set in the BackendLayout or else
  10 < .default
  10.value = colContent_1

  # 11 is in this case the colPos 10 set in the BackendLayout or else
  11 < .default
  11.value = colContent_2
}
```